# Web Part Page to select from list and display edit form

Tags: web-part

Using MOSS 2007, I'm trying to create a web part page that displays a filtered list of records on one column, and a connected single record edit view on another. I'd like to be able to select a radial button on the list and be able to edit that record on the 2nd web part (checking a complete box).

So far, I have the radial list and am able to display the single record in the other web part, but I'm not able to edit.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using ONLY out of the box web parts?

Comment: To the best of my understanding, yes.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use the display option in the list configuration?!? theres a option that looks very similar to what you said you want...

Comment: Yes, I tried to create a datasheet view and have the single record view use this configuration, but it breaks the link to the main web part.

Comment: not the datasheet view... on a regular view check the "Style" section... (below "Total" and on top of "Folders")

Comment: The styles are changing the way the single record is displayed, but are not allowing me to edit the record without navigating to a new screen.